# is it possible to parameterize QueueTrigger name?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I'm writing a queue-triggered azure function:

```
    [FunctionName("OnTranslationEventQueueTriggered")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("translationsqueue", Connection = "TranslationsQueueConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    }
```

The name of the queue is `translationsqueue`, but I'd like to be able to parameterize this.

**How do we pull the name of the queue from configuration?**

Comment: I am uncertain about what you mean by parameterize the trigger name and how it relates to configuration. Can you clarify. I must be misunderstanding what is being asked.

Comment: have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/

Comment: @Nkosi i dont want to hardcode `translationsqueue` - i want to be able to set this name in configurationn

Comment: QueueTrigger("%translationsqueue%", …)

Comment: Ok now I understand.

Comment: @RomanKiss you should post that as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [Binding expressions and patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions-and-patterns) the app setting binding expression is wrapped in percent signs, see the following example:

in the class:

```
QueueTrigger("%translationsqueue%", …)
```

in the bindings:

```
    {
      "bindings": [
       {
         "name": "myQueueItem",
         "type": "queueTrigger",
         "direction": "in",
         "queueName": "%translationsqueue%",
         "connection": "TranslationsQueueConnectionString"
       }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: whats the benefit of using the bindings vs regular configuration like from environment variables?

Comment: Where is this bindings section? Normally you have Values section in local.settings.json file and host.json file provided in Visual Studio project for an Azure Function.

Comment: @Oliver Functions.json is the bindings section